How to display HDR content in WebGL?
I'm curious to know if it is possible in a web app to display 10-bit HDR content that will leverage HDR capable displays such as Apple XDR displays and HDR-capable TV's as external displays, and such.
In particular from a WebGL context. Presumably we would want to specify the use of Display P3 color space as output. Something like that.
I'm interested in how, even if it means having to use Chrome on macOS to do it. But it should support HDR on Windows and macOS and iOS (and presumably Android).
Example: Three.js has HDR examples. But they are not "real" HDR. They're about working with HDR content in the GPU and performing tone mapping and such, but the output format is still regular 8 bit SDR content. True HDR content on a typical modern computer will allow brightness of the content to exceed the white content of the rest of the SDR content on-screen.

I found a related link. https://w3c.github.io/ColorWeb-CG/ Unclear what the status of vendor implementation is. Well... It states it is a "gap analysis document". So it seems to be a statement that this area constitutes a gap in the current specs.

I am collecting more links: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/3545 It's certainly looking like on a 2, maybe 3 year time frame native apps are the only way to go. Even though various capabilities are being added in browsers and you can see some in e.g. https://www.wide-gamut.com/test it seems a lot of "HDR video" hacks are used these days. Even today my mac still does weird stuff with its hardware and display brightness is unstable when HDR content exists somewhere in a browser.

Today I found this webgpu demo showing "extended" HDR rendering. When selecting "extended" toneMappingMode, it is a very obvious, bright effect for me. I'm testing in Chrome on an M1 Macbook Pro (aka "P3 XDR"). https://webgpu.github.io/webgpu-samples/?sample=particles

Thank you for sharing. It really does seem to work. I shall want to try it out in windows next. I found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/dynamic-range as well. But it is unclear to me right now how we could engage HDR for a particular canvas and what webgl/webgpu knobs we need to fiddle with to get it turned on (and to work out e.g. how to set luminance values in the extended color space to line up with the usual SDR max values).
